# LinkedHashMap порядок добавления

Tags: java

за счет чего сохраняется порядок добавления в LinkedHashMap?

Comment: что то мне подсказывает, что у него где то внутри есть связанный список

Comment: ну так и есть, походу помимо самой хеш таблицы, корзины, в которых хранятся ключи и значения в LinkedHashMap организованы в [связанный список](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#L316).

Comment: @tym32167 интуиция вас [не подводит](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#l204).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ну я примерно куда то туда же закинул ссылку

Comment: У каждой ноды хэшмапы (в которой ключ и значение) есть ссылки на следующую и предыдущую ноду.